# React app crashes when axios fetching data response with status code 404

Tags: reactjs, axios, swr

I getting started with React App using **Axios**, **SWR hook** for fetching data, it will work fine if i received response status code success 200/OK, but my app was crashed when status code are **404**, **403** or **500**.

My code:

*axiosConfig.js*

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosConfig = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
})

axiosConfig.interceptors.request.use(request => { 
  return request;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error)
})

axiosConfig.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  return response.data;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error)
})

export { axiosConfig }
```

*App.jsx*

```
import { Suspense } from 'react'
import { Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import { SWRConfig } from 'swr'

import routes from './routes'
import Loading from './components/Loading'
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent'

import { axiosConfig } from './axiosConfig'


const App = () => {

  return (
    <SWRConfig
      value={{
        fetcher: (url) => axiosConfig.get(url),
        dedupingInterval: 10000,
        shouldRetryOnError: false,
        revalidateOnFocus: false,
        suspense: true
      }}
    >  

      <main className="container">      
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<MyComponent/>} {...props} />
            // etc...
          </Routes>        
        </Suspense>
      </main>  

    </SWRConfig>  

  )
}
export default App;
```

*MyComponent.jsx*

```
import useSWR from "swr"

const MyComponent = () => {

    const { data, error } = useSWR('/post/1')

    if (error) return <div>Something went wrong!</div>

    return (
      // render UI
    )
}
```

I need handle error and show it inside MyComponent.jsx but it always crash. Who can helps me solve my problem?

Comment: the 404 status code means that some resource you specified in your in your app was not found so you need to figure out why. Could you please provide more information, like the error you're getting and your desired output(What you are trying to achieve)

Comment: @SebastianGbudje  I want to show my custom error component when status code > 201  instead of crashing the whole react app. The 404 status code that is my deliberately tested

Comment: You could simply do something like `res.status` after your axios call to get the status code. You could then pass the `res.status`  as a prop to your `MyComponent.jsx`  and write a check to see if the status code is 400 then render your error component.

Comment: @SebastianGbudje Oh!!! This worked perfectly if i disabled { suspense: false }, why?

Comment: @SebastianGbudje I just set  { suspense: false } in SWRConfig and it worked but i don't know why :))

Comment: "when you enabled suspense it's guaranteed that data will always be ready on render" -SWR Docs. My guess is that you won't  have the option of having undefined data which tends to break/crash apps so you won't be able to test your logic since the data is always there. Disabling that makes it so you do not have data available at all times. Meaning a check has to be done to avoid the app breaking

Comment: @SebastianGbudje Thanks a lot! I really appreciate that